# How to find third week of every month? Week 1 starts from the first Monday of the month

Tags: javascript, datepicker, calendar, momentjs, daterangepicker

I want to disable certain weeks for all the months available in calendar.
Week 1 starts from first Monday of that month. How can I get 3rd week(Monday to Sunday) of every month?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way to get the first Monday then you have a point at which you can go out from, just add 14 days to that and you have the third Monday, and then after that you just continue to get the rest of the week. You could do it with something like...

```
for i = 14 to 21
date.day(firstMonday + i) //and then whatever you want to do with it
```

Comment: My monday logic was not working properly, it was messing up my calendar. Do you have any other way?